# jQuery | Check Input type of select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I want to know how I can check the input of an option value.

I already have have a function where I can check radio buttons:

```
<div id="gender"> 
    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male">Male <br />
    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female">  Female   
</div>  

$("#gender input[type='radio']:checked").val();
    var gender = $("#gender input[type='radio']:checked").val();
    console.log(gender)
```

But how do I check this:

```
<div id="MaxPeople">
    <select>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's almost exactly like in your first piece of code - just get the `.val()` of the `select`, no need to check the `option`s yourself:

```
var max = $("#MaxPeople select").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the wrapper `div`'s id to select the `select` element and call the `val()` method to get the selected value

```
var maxPeople = $('#MaxPeople select').val();
console.log(maxPeople);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
var selectValue = $('#MaxPeople select').val();
```

and then check if the value is what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div#MaxPeople select").val("3"); //set value like this
```

Comment: He doesn't want to set the value.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question. In the first case, as it is a radio button, i thought check as set.. so gave answer to set